# VK API, можно ли посылать сообщения пользователю, который подал заявку на вступление в сообщество

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаем бота для сообщества ВКонтакте. Сообщество закрытое, то есть, чтобы в него выступить, нужно подать заявку на вступление, которую должна одобрить администрация.
Так вот вопрос: можно ли через метод `messages.send` отправить сообщение пользователю, которые подал заявку на вступление? И, авансом, еще вопрос: для работы с сообщениями сообщества надо проходить модерацию?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, заявка на вступление не дает сообществу право отправлять пользователю сообщение.
Нет, для работы с сообщениями сообщества нет необходимости проходить модерацию.

Comment: “Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.”